# How do i delay a function after the handled device ends shake?

Tags: c#, android, iphone, unity-game-engine, shake

I'm developing a game on Unity3d. Here I have 5 cards, and I'm trying to shuffle them with the shake movement, but, with my code, the cards are being shuffle while the shake is performed, I need that that function can be delayed or start when the shake ends. Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Shake1 : MonoBehaviour {

    int numTimes = 50;

    public Image personajes;
    public Image lugares;
    public Image situaciones;
    public Image emociones;
    public Image objetos;
    public GameObject camShake;


    float accelerometerUpdateInterval;
    // The greater the value of LowPassKernelWidthInSeconds, the slower the filtered value will converge towards current input sample (and vice versa).
    float lowPassKernelWidthInSeconds;
    // This next parameter is initialized to 2.0 per Apple's recommendation, or at least according to Brady! ;)
    float shakeDetectionThreshold ;

    float lowPassFilterFactor;

    Vector3 lowPassValue;
    Vector3 acceleration;
    Vector3 deltaAcceleration;

    void Start () {
        lowPassKernelWidthInSeconds = 1.0f;
        accelerometerUpdateInterval = 1.0f / 60.0f;
        lowPassValue  = Vector3.zero;
        lowPassFilterFactor = accelerometerUpdateInterval / lowPassKernelWidthInSeconds;
    }
    public Vector3 LowPassFilter(Vector3 newSample){
        lowPassValue = Vector3.Lerp (lowPassValue, newSample,lowPassFilterFactor);
        return lowPassValue;    
    }

    void Update () {
        acceleration = Input.acceleration;
        deltaAcceleration = acceleration - LowPassFilter (acceleration);

        if (Mathf.Abs (deltaAcceleration.x) >= 0.2 && Mathf.Abs (deltaAcceleration.y) >= 0.2 && Mathf.Abs (deltaAcceleration.z) >= 0.2) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numTimes; i++) {
                Handheld.Vibrate();
                if (personajes.transform.parent.name == "Panel_Superior") {
                    personajes.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Cartas/pillow-cards-" + Random.Range (2, 13)) as Sprite;
                }
                if (situaciones.transform.parent.name == "Panel_Superior") {
                    situaciones.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Cartas/pillow-cards-" + Random.Range (28, 39)) as Sprite;
                }
                if (emociones.transform.parent.name == "Panel_Superior") {
                    emociones.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Cartas/pillow-cards-" + Random.Range (41, 52)) as Sprite;
                }
                if (lugares.transform.parent.name == "Panel_Superior") {
                    lugares.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Cartas/pillow-cards-" + Random.Range (15, 26)) as Sprite;
                }
                if (objetos.transform.parent.name == "Panel_Superior") {
                    objetos.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Cartas/pillow-cards-" + Random.Range (54, 68)) as Sprite;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what is `numTimes` for?

Comment: you use **Invoke** for timers in Unity.  very easy.

Answer (score 0):

As `Update()` is called at 60Hz, you can create a counter (let's say it's called `zeroAcc`) that is increased everytime the acceleration is below your triggering threshold of "shake".
At the same time that the shake is triggered, you can store the value of `zeroAcc` at that moment, let's say `accTri`.
Now you need to decide the delay, that could for this example be 30 calls of `Update()`, and then trigger the callback.
It could look like this:

```
void Update(){
//keep your code you already have and add this:
    if (zeroAcc - accTri > 30) {
        callback ();
        accTri = int.MaxValue; //we don't want to trigger again
    }
}
```